# Custom print text file in richedTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Helo to all. I have a text file called mytext.txt and inside the text have a format like this:

```
<name1>Myname
age
address
postal code
<name2>Myname
age
address
postal code
....(more of the same)
```

the problem i have is that i must print this text in a richTextBox in format like this:

```
<name1>Myname
    -age
    -address
    -postal code
<name2>Myname
    -age
    -address
    -postal code
....(more of the same)
```

any idea how i must do this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what UI framework are you using? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var writer = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("mytext.txt"))
{
   writer.AppendLine(!line.StartsWith("<") ? string.Format("  -{0}", line) : line);
}

richTextBox1.Text = writer.ToString();
```

Comment: This one works great.
The litle change i made was this: stirng.Format("\t-{0}" : line);

Answer (score 3):

I won't give you the exact code, but I can give you a pseudo-code representation of what a working algorithm would look like:

```
 function printTextFile()
 {
     for(every line in the text file) 
         // So start the loop through each line.
         if(current line does not start with "<")
         {
             prefix:= "    -".
             // So we're not at a title part.
         }

         print(prefix + current line).
         // Print out the line with the indent.
         prefix:= "".
         // reset the prefix.
     end for loop.
 }
```